# How to drop MongoDB field using PyMODM and Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, pymodm

How can I drop/delete a field from the document when it is already created using [PyMoDM](https://pymodm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

I have following model:

```
class User(MongoModel):
    email = fields.EmailField(required=True)
    password = fields.CharField(required=True)
    first_name = fields.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = fields.CharField(blank=True)
```

I have a user with all the fields. After deleting `last_name` from the model next "get" throws an error: `ValueError: Unrecognized field name 'last_name'`

```
user = User.objects.get({'email': email.lower()})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue and understand this to be a bug. I have [created an issue to help reslove it.](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYMODM-48)

If you needed to remove all the `last_name` fields from your User collection you could use the underlying pymongo connection like so:

```
pymodm.connection._get_db()['user'].update_many({}, {"$unset":{"last_name":""}})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will vote for your issue and hope it will be fixed soon.